# Which hook for processing plugin page form data?

Tags: admin, dashboard, admin-init

Which hook should I use for processing form data from my plugin pages. I currently use *"admin_init"*. Is that correct? Was this hook intended to be used this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're processing data submitted from a custom form, then I'd say the init hook is the best hook to use. See [example 1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init).

Comment: Would it be because of the fact it's fired earlier? Seems very reasonable.

Comment: Guess it depends on what you're doing. Init is the first hook where it is safe to run custom code knowing that everything is loaded. It's also great for using wp_redirect which needs to run before anything is output to the browser. Admin init is when the admin interface is ready so if your plugin is doing stuff on the front end, admin init is probably no good.

Answer (score 1):

For processing plugin options I assume that you created some kind of an options page?

Here's an example of creating a checkbox setting inside an options page, with validation and everything else. Just create a new "myplugin-admin.php" file and insert the code. There's only one setting: remove junk from wp's  area. Then include the admin file inside your main plugin php file (e.g. myplugin.php) -> include "myplugin-admin.php";

```
<?php

// SETUP THE MENU
function myplugin_setup_menu(){
        add_options_page( 'Settings', 'MyPlugin', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'myplugin_build_options_page' );
}

// BUILD OPTIONS PAGE
function myplugin_build_options_page(){ ?>

<div id="myplugin" class="wrap">

    <div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"></div>

    <h2 class="options-title">MyPlugin <?php _e("Settings"); ?></h2>

    <form method="post" action="options.php" class="options-form">

        <div id="poststuff">
            <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-2">

                <!-- main content -->
                <div id="post-body-content">
                    <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
                        <div class="postbox">
                            <h3 class="hndle"><span><?php _e("General"); ?> <?php _e("Settings"); ?></span></h3>
                            <div class="inside">

                                <?php settings_fields('myplugin_options'); ?>
                                <?php do_settings_sections(__FILE__); ?>

                            </div><!-- .inside -->
                        </div><!-- .postbox -->
                    </div><!-- .meta-box-sortables .ui-sortable -->
                </div><!-- post-body-content -->

                <!-- sidebar -->
                <div id="postbox-container-1" class="postbox-container">
                    <div class="meta-box-sortables">
                        <div class="postbox">

                            <div class="inside">
                                <p><?php _e("Edit MyPLugin Settings"); ?></p>
                            </div><!-- .inside -->

                        </div><!-- .postbox -->
                    </div><!-- .meta-box-sortables -->
                </div><!-- #postbox-container-1 .postbox-container -->
            </div><!-- #post-body .metabox-holder .columns-2 -->
            <br class="clear">

            <?php myplugin_submit(); ?>

        </div><!-- #poststuff -->

    </form><!-- /.options-form -->

</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php }

/* ================================================================ *\
    BUILD AND REGISTER OPTIONS
\* ================================================================

register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback );
    $option_group: a string representing the name of the settings group
    $option_name: the name of the option
    $sanitize_callback: a callback function that can handle any specific operations or sanitizing

add_settings_section( $id, $title, $callback, $page );
    $id: a unique ID for the section
    $title: a heading that will be displayed above the fields on the page
    $callback: can handle the creation of the section; if it’s declared, you must create the function, or an error will be thrown
    $page: defines the type of settings page that this section should be applied to; in our case, it should apply to our custom page, so we used __FILE__ as the name

add_settings_field( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args );
    $id: a unique ID for the field
    $title: the title before the field
    $callback: handles the displaying of the field
    $page: it should apply to our custom page, so we used __FILE__ as the name
    $section: set the section the the field belongs to
    $args: ka
*/
function myplugin_build_options () {
    $options = get_option('lmyplugin_options');
    if(!isset($options)) {
        //not present, so add
        $options = array(
            'remove_junk' => 1
        );
        add_option('myplugin_options', $options);
    }

    // Register Settings
    register_setting('myplugin_options', 'myplugin_options', 'myplugin_validate_settings');

    // Add Sections
    add_settings_section('myplugin_section_functions', __("Functions", "myplugin"), 'myplugin_section_functions_cb', __FILE__);

    /*
        ADD FIELDS TO SECTION
    */

    // Remove Junk
    add_settings_field('remove_junk', __('Remove Junk from Head', 'myplugin'), 'myplugin_setting_remove_junk', __FILE__, 'myplugin_section_functions');
}

// VALIDATE SETTINGS
function myplugin_validate_settings($options) {
    return $options;
}

// SETTINGS SECTION CLLBACK
function myplugin_section_functions_cb() {}

/* ================================================================ *\
    BUILD SETTINGS FIELDS
\* ================================================================ */

// Remove Junk
function myplugin_setting_remove_junk() {
    $options = get_option('myplugin_options'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php _e("Remove Junk from <head>", 'myplugin'); ?></span></legend>
        <label for="remove_junk">
            <input name="myplugin_options[remove_junk]" type="checkbox" id="remove_junk" value="1" <?php checked($options['remove_junk'], 1, true); ?> />
            <span><?php _e( 'Remove junk information from wordpress <head> area.', 'myplugin' ); ?></span>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
<?php }

/* ================================================================ *\
    MISC
\* ================================================================ */

// SUBMIT BUTTON
function myplugin_submit() { ?>
    <p class="submit"><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes'); ?>" /><!-- /#.button-primary --></p><!-- /.submit -->
<?php }

// ADD STYLESHEET
function myplugin_register_head() {
    $url = plugins_url('css/admin-style.css', __FILE__ );
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$url.'" />';
}

// ADD ACTIONS
add_action('admin_head', 'myplugin_register_head');
add_action('admin_init', 'myplugin_build_options');
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin_setup_menu');


?>
```

Have fun trying that out and I hope I could help you.

Comment: So basically 'admin_init' is the hook. In your code I see myplugin_build_options function with it. That's exactly what I meant.